# Using converter in JavaServer Faces

Tags: jsf, converters, label

I have that converter:

```
public class PollConverter implements Converter {

    private static PollanswersDao pollsDao = new PollanswersDao();

    public Object getAsObject(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, String value) {
        return pollsDao.read(Long.parseLong(value));
    }

    public String getAsString(FacesContext context, UIComponent component, Object value) {
        return String.valueOf(((PollanswersEntity)value).getId());
    }
}
```

In faces-config.xml:

```
<converter>
    <converter-id>PollsConverter</converter-id>
    <converter-class>org.test.majas.converters.PollConverter</converter-class>
</converter>
```

So, I can unique identify poll only by ID. Ok I use this converter:

```
<h:form>
    <h:selectOneRadio layout="pageDirection" value="#{votesBean.answer}">
        <f:converter converterId="PollsConverter"/>
        <f:selectItems value="#{pollsBean.selectItems}" var="item" itemLabel="#{item.value.title}" />
    </h:selectOneRadio>
    <h:messages/>
    <h:commandButton value="#{msgs.vote}" action="#{votesBean.addVote}"/>
</h:form>
```

But this itemLabel="#{item.value.title}" not working. My selectItems itemlabels are ID values... How can I show itemLabels as objects "title" fields.

PollsBean:

```
@Named
@SessionScoped
public class PollsBean implements Serializable {
    ...

    private List<SelectItem> selectItems;

    ...

    public List<SelectItem> getSelectItems() {
        return selectItems;
    }

    public void setSelectItems(List<SelectItem> selectItems) {
        this.selectItems = selectItems;
    }

...

}
```

Thanks.

Comment: _"Not working"_ means nothing is displayed or a thrown exception ?  
And how does `PollsBean`'s structure look like ?

Comment: Not working - displayed items ID, without this attribute items ID are displayed too. I have added PollsBean structure to question.

Comment: Select item is javax.faces.model.SelectItem :)

Comment: What's the purpose of using this predefined class as an ordinary class, as object in the code ? Does it contain `Value` composite class which has `title` as a field ?

Comment: Yes value is object of a class with title field.

Comment: What's showed instead of what is desired to be ?

Comment: Showed item ID (from converter getAsString)